# How to add ec2 instance in aws ecs empty cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

please let me know is there is a way to add ec2 instance is empty ecs cluster , firstly i created a ecs empty cluster and it didnt automatic make IAM role. And i have tried with ecs config file .

Answer (score 2):

The new instance should be running ECS agent and should have desired permission to registry against ECS cluster.

During launching the instance add these in the user data section.
`ECS_CLUSTER=your_cluster_name`
This is importent, it will join the desired cluster.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=your_cluster_name >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config;echo ECS_BACKEND_HOST= >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config;
```

[/launch_container_instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html)

[register-container-instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/register-container-instance.html)

**Amazon ECS Container Agent**

> The Amazon ECS container agent allows container instances to connect
>   to your cluster.

So its mean you can not connect with out ECS agent.

[ECS_agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_agent.html)

If everything goes fine then it should connect to ECS cluster, normally reason that may cause

> However, if your container agent remains in a disconnected state, then
>   the container instance can't operate as part of your ECS cluster. Your
>   agent is disconnected when agentConnected returns false. The issue can
>   be caused by the following:

- Networking issues prevent communication between the instance and Amazon ECS
- The container agent doesn't have the required AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) permissions to communicate with Amazon ECS endpoints
- There are problems with the host or Docker service inside the container instance

[ecs-agent-disconnected-linux2-ami](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-agent-disconnected-linux2-ami/)